# How to 'Pass' on multiple Greater Than Checks

Tags: javascript, math

Say you have the number `var n = 1,000,000;`

I want to check:

```
n >= 1e3
n >= 1e4
n >= 1e5
n >= 1e6
```

Doing it exactly as it looks above will cause the statement to return true on the first valid expression, obviously. Which means that it will say `n is greater than 1e3` and return the results from there.

How can I get it to instead 'cascade' through the expressions until it hits a false, then use the last statement that was true, without having to go:

```
if( n >= 1e3 && n >= 1e4 && n >= 1e5 && n >= 1e6  ) {...
```

Comment: Only `n >= 1e6` is enough

Comment: You're aware that `n >= 1e3 && n >= 1e4` can be simplified to `n >= 1e4`? Also, if you're just interested for the magnitude of `n`, use `log10`.

Comment: Yeah... wondering why I typed that in the question now! Sorry I should have also mentioned that n can constantly change also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the number from the biggest to the smalest:

```js
var n = 1000000;
var r = document.getElementById("result");
if (n >= 1e6) r.innerHTML = "n >= 1e6";
else if (n >= 1e5) r.innerHTML ="n >= 1e5";
else if (n >= 1e4) r.innerHTML ="n >= 1e4";
else if (n >= 1e3) r.innerHTML = "n >= 1e3";
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

If you need to have all the diffent sentences, you can do:

```js
var r = document.getElementById("result");
var n = 1000000;
var str = "";
if (n >= 1e6) str += "n >= 1e6 ";
if (n >= 1e5) str += "n >= 1e5 ";
if (n >= 1e4) str += "n >= 1e4 ";
if (n >= 1e3) str += "n >= 1e3 ";
r.innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

To have something more maintainable and extendable :

```js
var n = 1000000;
var r = document.getElementById("result");
check(n, [1000, 1e4, 1e5, 1e6]);
function check(nb, limits) {
 limits.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
    var limitsLength = limits.length;
    for (var i =0;i<limitsLength;i++) {
     if (nb >= limits[i]) r.innerHTML += "n >= 1e" + Math.log10(limits[i]) + " ";
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Good Shout! Thanks Magic :)

Answer (score 1):

No need for branching.

```
function yours() {
    if (n < 1) return 'n is less than 1e0';
    return 'n is greater than 1e' + Math.log10(n);
}
```

If you must branch (for example if you are actually calculating something more complex than a simple logarithm), add a new function to avoid the "cascading" you mention. The return statements will prevent cascading. The new function defines how much stuff gets skipped.

```
function yours() {
    println(figure(n));
}

function figure(n) {
    if (n > 10000) return 'n is greater than 1e4';
    if (n > 1000) return 'n is greater than 1e3';
    if (n > 100) return 'n is greater than 1e2';
    if (n > 10) return 'n is greater than 1e1';
    if (n > 1) return 'n is greater than 1e0';
}
```

I'm using `println` here as a substitute for whatever you want to do with the result.